# Routing in Express and MEAN stack

Tags: node.js, express, mean-stack

I am following an on-line tutorial of implementing in MEAN. Everything looks great. Except when it comes to routes. I understand that routes need to be in a javascript files (js extension). It's okay with a small web site. But as the number of requests grow, I would like to put them in separate files. I looked up in SOF for how to include files in Javascript. It is non-trivial. Has anyone faced this issue before? Can anyone comment?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Router Middleware](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.router) by using `express.Router()`. This allows you to break your routes into different files. On a side note, middleware is very powerful and is worth learning about, its a huge part of Express.

Say you have an app that has a `/users` section. You can create a separate routes file called `users.js` that contains all routes that pertain to your `/users` resources. Then inside your `server.js` where your main Express app is listening, you can assign the `users.js` routes to the `/users` resource using `app.use()`.

You can have as many routers as you'd like, all routes are read top-down when Express is deciding which route to use.

**./routes/users.js**

```
// Create an express router
var router = require('express').Router();

// Define a route for GET /
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.status(200).send('Welcome to /users');
});

// make our router available for require() statements
module.exports = router;
```

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

// Users routes
var users = require('./routes/users');

// Tell our app to use the Users routes defined in ./routes/users.js
app.use('/users', users);

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function() {
  console.log('listening');
});
```

Comment: Thans. You are the best!

Comment: @user2654788 np, if this was indeed the answer, please mark it as the answer so future visitors to this question will know that this was what answered your question.